# Find required files by pattern and the change the pattern on Linux

Tags: linux

I need to find all *.xml files that matched by pattern on Linux. I need to have written the file name on the screen and then change the pattern in the file just was found.

For instance.

I can start the script with arguments for keyword and for value, i.e

script.sh keyword "another word"

Script should find all files with keyword  and do the following changes in the files containing keyword.

```
<keyword></keyword> should be the same <keyword></keyword>
<keyword>some word</keyword> should be like this <keyword>some word, another word</keyword>
```

In other words if initially value in keyword node was empty, then I don't need to change it and if it contains some value then I need to extend it with the value I will specify.

What is best way to do this on Linux? Using find, grep, sed?
Performance is also important since the number of files are thousands.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems using a combination of find, grep and sed would do this and they are pretty fast since you'll be doing text processing so there *might* not be a need for xml processing but if you could you give an example or rephrase your question I might be able to provide more help.